# In which iOS version, atomic/nonatomic were added?

Tags: ios, atomic

In which iOS version, atomic/nonatomic were added? iOS 2.0 , 4.0 etc

Comment: They have been there since the beginning if I remember correctly.

Comment: They have been here since the introduction of `@property` in Objective-C 2.0, in 2006, before iOS existed.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an iOS SDK version feature. It's the Objective-C compiler's (LLVM by default) language feature.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString* prop;
```

gets translated to machine code that's executed by iOS. One day somebody taught the **compiler** (in XCode) : if you see `nonatomic` keyword produc machine code equal to this operation:

```
- (void) setProp:(NSString *)prop_ {
    [prop retain];
    [prop release];
    prop = userName_;
}
```

if you see `atomic` keyword make sure the access is synchronized:

```
 - (void) setProp:(NSString*)prop_ {
     @synchronized(self) {
       [prop release];
       prop = [prop_ retain];
     } }
```

After it gets compiled every iOS version will understand it.

Answer (score 2):

The last two are identical; "atomic" is the default behavior (note that it is not actually a keyword; it is specified only by the absence of nonatomic).
Assuming that you are @synthesizing the method implementations, atomic vs. non-atomic changes the generated code. If you are writing your own setter/getters, atomic/nonatomic/retain/assign/copy are merely advisory.
With "atomic", the synthesized setter/getter will ensure that a whole value is always returned from the getter or set by the setter, regardless of setter activity on any other thread. That is, if thread A is in the middle of the getter while thread B calls the setter, an actual viable value -- an autoreleased object, most likely -- will be returned to the caller in A.
In nonatomic, no such guarantees are made. Thus, nonatomic is considerably faster than "atomic".